# drupal 7 how to use drupal_goto for file

Tags: drupal-7, filefield

I did some custom scripting in a custom module. After my scripting I would like to go to the file path of a file field.
How can I achive this?
I have the uri of the file to display it. 
I tried 
drupal_goto('$result') 
where $result is result of query with uri field of file.

Although 
drupal_goto($result) does not work.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

```
drupal_goto(file_create_url($result));
```

The uri contains public://

If this doesnt work, print the result of file_create_url($result) and copy past it in your browser see if the file is really there. By the way, you should avoid querying the database just for one file and use a file_load() to avoid bad surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this realy helped me in the good direction...

```
Now I used this
$file = file_load($fid);
$uri = $file->uri;
$url = file_create_url($uri);

drupal_goto($url);
```

Hope this will help someone :-)